# How to get a new date from two date(hour) columns

Tags: python, datetime

I have a dataframe including a datetime column for date and a column for date of change.
Example:

```
    obdate      cdate
0   2015-01-04  11
0   2016-03-20  7
0   2017-07-15  14d20h
0   2017-12-14  12
```

I need a new datetime column based on the `cdate` column.
Example:

```
    obdate      cdate     newdate
0   2015-01-04  11        2015-01-04 11:00:00
0   2016-03-20  7         2016-03-20 07:00:00
0   2017-07-15  14d20h    2017-07-14 20:00:00
0   2017-12-14  12        2017-12-14 12:00:00
```

How can I do it?

Comment: what did you try? Where is your code? You can use `df.apply(your_function, axis=1)` to run `your_function(row)` for every row and this `your_function` could use standard module `datetime` to create date with time. Or you could use normal string functions for this.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `df.apply(your_function, axis=1)` to run `your_function(row)` for every `row` and this `your_function` could use standard module `datetime` to create date with time. Or it can use normal string functions for this.

---

I use `io.StringIO` only to simulate file in memory.

```
text ='''obdate      cdate
2015-01-04  11
2016-03-20  7
2017-07-15  14d20h
2017-12-14  12'''

import pandas as pd
#import datetime
import io

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(text), sep='\s+')

def function(row):
    date = row['obdate']
    try:
        hour = int(row['cdate'])
        return f"{date} {hour:02}:00:00"
    except ValueError:
        date = date[:-2]  # skip day in `date`
        day, hour = row['cdate'].split('d')
        hour = hour[:-1]  # skip `h`
        day  = int(day)
        hour = int(hour)
        return f"{date}{day:02} {hour:02}:00:00"

df['newdate'] = df.apply(function, axis=1)

print(df)
```

Result:

```
       obdate   cdate              newdate
0  2015-01-04      11  2015-01-04 11:00:00
1  2016-03-20       7  2016-03-20 07:00:00
2  2017-07-15  14d20h  2017-07-14 20:00:00
3  2017-12-14      12  2017-12-14 12:00:00
```